# Best Clustering Method for Dataset with Few Distinct Values

Tags: clustering, recommender-system, unsupervised-learning

I have a dataset that has the opinions of 30 different TV shows for 2000 high school students.

A student could have said they liked the show, did not have an opinion, or disliked the show. These values then translate to [1,0,-1] in my dataset.

I would now like to find approx 10-20 clusters of student types based on this dataset.

Because there are only 3 unique values in each field, it seems like this data should follow clustering rules for binary data (ex: avoid kmeans). I have been reading literature on that but am still struggling to determine what the best methods would be.

If anyone has any input on what would be best, I would really appreciate it!

Below is smaller example of the dataset:

| Student | Friends | Seinfeld | HIMYM | Cheers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Student A | 1 | 1 | 1 | -1 |
| Student B | 1 | 0 | 0 | -1 |
| Student C | 0 | 1 | -1 | -1 |

Comment: why don't you want to use kmeans?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a "best" method in clustering.
Here are some ideas (all use k-means in the end though):

1. Read this [Netflix price](https://datajobs.com/data-science-repo/Recommender-Systems-%5BNetflix%5D.pdf) paper and try to use matrix decomposition to assign each student a vector of small dimension, then cluster these vectors using k-means.
2. Choose a random matrix of dimensions d x 30, with row vectors standardized to length one, and d small. Multiply with your dataset. Try to cluster the resulting 2000 points of dimension d using k-means.
3. Or just use k-means because dimension 30 is not that large :).